# Transferring Mosaic Datasets to ArcGIS Online?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-online, tilecache, mosaic-dataset

I have a number of mosaic datasets that I have created that I would like to upload to my ArcGIS online map.  How would I go about doing this?  I read somewhere to create a tile cache from the mosaic, then export it as a tile package, then use the "share package" tool to transfer it online.  Will this work?  I'm fairly new to GIS. (And if it makes a difference, these mosaics are all very large; around 300 MB a piece).

Answer (score 2):

This doc section should help you, it outlines the steps necessary to get your mosaic data to ArcGIS Online

http://server.arcgis.com/en/server/latest/publish-services/linux/share-imagery-as-an-arcgis-online-tiled-map-service.htm